# EXTJS conditionally hide icon

Tags: extjs

I have an EXTJS grid with 2 actioncolumns with icons only. How do I set the renderer to hide the icon if IsApproved = true? I've tried this.columns[0].items[0].icon = ''; but get an error of this.columns isn't defined.

```
columns: [
                    { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name', flex: 1 },
                    { header: 'Login', dataIndex: 'Login', flex: 1 },
                    { header: 'Registered', dataIndex: 'RegisteredOn', flex: 1 },
                    { header: 'Invited', dataIndex: 'InvitationSent', flex: 1 },
                    { xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                        width: 40,
                        header: 'Invite',
                        tdCls: 'clickable',
                        renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                            if (record.get('IsApproved')) {
                               //HIDE ICON
                            } else {
                                //SHOW ICON
                            }
                        },
                        items: [{
                            icon: '/images/icon_email.png',
                            tooltip: 'Invite',
                            scope: this,
                            handler: this.inviteClick
                        }]
                    },
                    { xtype: 'actioncolumn', width: 40, header: 'Edit', tdCls: 'clickable', items: [{
                        icon: '/images/pencil.png',
                        tooltip: 'Edit',
                        scope: this,
                        handler: this.editClick
                    }]
                    }
                ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try my way - if your condition true, so you put icon in cell, in other situation, you don't:

```
                {
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    width: 70,
                    align: 'center',
                    dataIndex: 'yourDataIndex',
                    menuDisabled: 'true',
                    text: 'sometext',
                    sortable: false,
                    fixed: 'true',
                    renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                        if (record.get('IsApproved')) {
                            metadata.tdCls = 'mycss'
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and add css for your situation:

```
.mycss {
    background-position:center  !important;
    width: auto !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("yourIcon.png") !important; 
}
```

Comment: That works for hiding the icon. But the link action is still there. (Sorry, didn't mention the link needs to be removed as well).

Comment: you:"But the link action is still there." Where is your link in your question?

Comment: with the handler: this.inviteClick

Comment: in your function this.inviteClick you should check cell value: if(!record.get('IsApproved')) do nothing)

Comment: Right, but can I remove the onclick from that cell altogether so there is no hand cursor or anything to click on at all?

Comment: Oops, forgot it set the clickable tdcls right there as well. All set. Thanks!

Comment: So, it seems that when I removed the icon = "x.png" from the item array, the click handler went with it. The iconclass is making the icon appear on the right rows, but my click event isnt happening now. Any thoughts?

Comment: `renderer` is not a config property of `actioncolumn` in Extjs 4